# How to retrieve specific profile variables from Watson's Dialog service via the watson-developer-cloud library

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-dialog

When retrieving profile variables from **Watson's Dialog** service, there is a parameter called ***name*** which allows you to control which variables are retrieved. If this parameter is blank, all variables that are associated with the specified client_id are returned. Otherwise, only the specified variables in ***name*** are returned.

I finally figured out how to specify more than one variable name on a direct GET to the REST API (give them all the same name, like `&name=var1&name=var2`), but I can't figure out how to do this via the watson-developer-cloud library.  It seems that no matter how I specify names in the `dialog.getProfile()` function call, it always returns ***all*** of the variables.

Can someone tell me how to do this?  I don't want to fetch them all every time and then search them for the one I want.

Comment: This question is more for Watson-Developer-Cloud library and not the dialog service directly. Rest API for dialog is here: http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/apis/dialog-apis.html#!/Profile/getProfile Seems the main documentation might be out of date, or functionality changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [bug](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/issues/207) in the library that was preventing `name` from being sent to the service.

Please update the library by doing

```
npm install watson-developer-cloud
```

And try with the example below

```
var params = {
  dialog_id: '<dialog id here>',
  client_id: '<client id here>',
  name: ['var1', 'var2']
};

dialog.getProfile(params, function(err, response){
  console.log(response)
});
```